# Extra sprite spawning when the enemies are redrawn SFML

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I am making a game in sfml and at the moment when all of the enemies die. They are set to respawn however when this is happening they are respawning with one extra sprite than before.

The code for loading in the sprites is

```
unsigned int orcNumber = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < orcNumber; i++)
{
    SpriteVector.push_back(ogreSprite);
    SpriteVector[i].setPosition(spawnPointX[i], spawnPointY[i]);
}
```

The code for removing the enemies if they are offscreen or shot is similar to below using erase.

```
for (unsigned j = 0; j < SpriteVector.size(); j++)
{
    if (this->SpriteVector[j].getPosition().x < 0 - 80 )
    {
        //this succesfully removes the object from the vector
        SpriteVector.erase(SpriteVector.begin() + j); 
        std::cout << "Container size..." << SpriteVector.size() << "\n";
    }
}
```

The statement for redrawing them is:

```
unsigned int orcNumberRespawn = 5;
if (SpriteVector.size() <= 1)
{           
    for (int i = 0; i < orcNumberRespawn; i++)
    {
        SpriteVector.push_back(ogreSprite);
        SpriteVector[i].setPosition(spawnPointX[i], spawnPointY[i]);
    }
}

window.draw(SpriteVector[i]);
```

Can anyone identify why when the sprites need to be redrawn it draws with + 1 sprite everytime?

Comment: x-post: http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=17770.0

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with a loop outside of these vector loops.